# ¿Cómo puedo centrar estas cajas sin usar un div, con CSS?

Tags: html, css

He de colocar estos elementos de manera que se vean así:
[image: Resultado final]

Bien, he conseguido que se vean de esta manera cuando mantienes la página del navegador en pantalla completa, pero en cuanto haces la ventana más pequeña, todo se mueve.
[image: Problema]
Soy consciente que es debido a que le he asignado la posición utilizando píxeles, pero he probado de hacerlo de todas las maneras posibles y no hay forma de conseguir lo que quiero.

Este es el código sobre el que trabajo (el cual no he de modificar, en un principio):

```
<h1>Groucho Marx</h1>

<p id="m1">Hijo mío, la felicidad está hecha de pequeñas cosas: Un pequeño yate, una pequeña mansión, una pequeña fortuna….</p>

<p id="m2">Estos son mis principios. Si no le gustan tengo otros.</p>

<p id="m3">El matrimonio es la principal causa de divorcio.</p>

<p id="m4">¿Servicio de habitaciones? Mándenme una habitación más grande.</p>

<p id="m5">Desde el momento en que cogí su libro me caí al suelo rodando de risa. Algún día espero leerlo.</p>

<p id="m6">Partiendo de la nada hemos alcanzado las más altas cotas de miseria.</p>
```

y este es mi documento CSS:

```
h1 {text-align: center;}
#m1 {background-color: #dccda4; border-style:solid; padding:1%; border-color: #a08d59; text-align: center; height:max-content; width:750px;  margin:auto;}

#m2 {background-color: #8bdb92; border-style:solid; padding:1%; border-color: #47b650; text-align: center; height:180px; width: 350px;position: absolute; z-index: 2;left: 750px; top:400px;} 
#m3 {background-color: #f8ffb4; border-style:solid; padding:1%; border-color: #ced495; text-align: left; height:180px; width: 350px;
position: absolute; z-index:1; top:280px; left:500px}
#m3:hover{
z-index: 3;}
#m4 {background-color: #b7ffff; border-style:solid; padding:1%; border-color: #9cdbdb; text-align: right; height:180px; width: 350px;
position:absolute;z-index: 1; top:280px;left:1000px;}
#m4:hover{z-index: 3;}
#m5 {background-color: #ffddfb; border-style:solid; padding:1%; border-color: #ceafca; text-align: left; height:180px; width: 350px;position: absolute; z-index:1; top:540px;left:500px}
#m5:hover{z-index:3;}
#m6 {background-color: #ffaaaf; border-style:solid; padding:1%; border-color: #c4777c; text-align: right; height:180px; width: 350px;
position: absolute; z-index:1; top:540px;left:1000px;}   
#m6:hover{z-index: 3;}
```

No entiendo cómo colocarlo y he buscado muchísima información.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#m1 {
  background-color: #dccda4;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-color: #a08d59;
  text-align: center;
  height: max-content;
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
}

#m2 {
  background-color: #8bdb92;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-color: #47b650;
  text-align: center;
  height: 180px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 750px;
  top: 400px;
}

#m3 {
  background-color: #f8ffb4;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-color: #ced495;
  text-align: left;
  height: 180px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 280px;
  left: 500px
}

#m3:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

#m4 {
  background-color: #b7ffff;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-color: #9cdbdb;
  text-align: right;
  height: 180px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 280px;
  left: 1000px;
}

#m4:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

#m5 {
  background-color: #ffddfb;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-color: #ceafca;
  text-align: left;
  height: 180px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 540px;
  left: 500px
}

#m5:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

#m6 {
  background-color: #ffaaaf;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-color: #c4777c;
  text-align: right;
  height: 180px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 540px;
  left: 1000px;
}

#m6:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Groucho Marx</h1>

<p id="m1">Hijo mío, la felicidad está hecha de pequeñas cosas: Un pequeño yate, una pequeña mansión, una pequeña fortuna….</p>

<p id="m2">Estos son mis principios. Si no le gustan tengo otros.</p>

<p id="m3">El matrimonio es la principal causa de divorcio.</p>

<p id="m4">¿Servicio de habitaciones? Mándenme una habitación más grande.</p>

<p id="m5">Desde el momento en que cogí su libro me caí al suelo rodando de risa. Algún día espero leerlo.</p>

<p id="m6">Partiendo de la nada hemos alcanzado las más altas cotas de miseria.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como tu dices, el problema se debe a que usas pixeles y se soluciona empleando unidades relativas como `%`, `vh`, `vw` etc

No obstante yo lo haría usando `display:grid` y solo el cuadro verde lo haría con `position:absolute`

algo asi:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 350px 350px;
    grid-template-rows: 88px 180px 180px;
    gap: 0px 110px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: max-content;
}
.cuadro{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1%;
    border-style: solid;
}
#m1 {
  background-color: #dccda4;
  border-color: #a08d59;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

#m2 {
  background-color: #8bdb92;
  border-color: #47b650;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 180px;
  width: 350px;
  left: calc(50% - 175px);
  top: calc(50% - 90px);
  
}

#m3 {
  background-color: #f8ffb4;
  border-color: #ced495;
  text-align: left;
}

#m3:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

#m4 {
  background-color: #b7ffff;
  border-color: #9cdbdb;
  text-align: right;
}

#m4:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

#m5 {
  background-color: #ffddfb;
  border-color: #ceafca;
  text-align: left;
}

#m5:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

#m6 {
  background-color: #ffaaaf;
  border-color: #c4777c;
  text-align: right;
}

#m6:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Groucho Marx</h1>
<div id="grid">

<p id="m1" class="cuadro">Hijo mío, la felicidad está hecha de pequeñas cosas: Un pequeño yate, una pequeña mansión, una pequeña fortuna….</p>

<p id="m2" class="cuadro">Estos son mis principios. Si no le gustan tengo otros.</p>

<p id="m3" class="cuadro">El matrimonio es la principal causa de divorcio.</p>

<p id="m4" class="cuadro">¿Servicio de habitaciones? Mándenme una habitación más grande.</p>

<p id="m5" class="cuadro">Desde el momento en que cogí su libro me caí al suelo rodando de risa. Algún día espero leerlo.</p>

<p id="m6" class="cuadro">Partiendo de la nada hemos alcanzado las más altas cotas de miseria.</p>
</div>
```